# multiple count on derived table

Tags: sql-server, derived-table

I am trying to count total shortlisted and total interested by using a derived table but it's not working.

```
select  (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Dtable WHERE Is_shortlisted=1) AS TOTALSHORLISTED,           
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Dtable WHERE Is_Interested=1) AS TOTALINERESTED 
from (
        SELECT  BM.ID,
                BM.Is_Interested,
                BM.Is_shortlisted,
                BM.Business_Masla_Status_ID
        FROM  Business_Maslahal BM
        INNER join Vw_MaslaInfo MI 
            on BM.[MaslaHal_ID]=MI.ID and BM.ID=2 AND MI.Masla_status_ID IN(1,2) 
) Dtable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't even need the derived table:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Is_shortlisted=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALSHORLISTED,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Is_Interested=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALINERESTED 
FROM  Business_Maslahal BM
INNER join Vw_MaslaInfo MI 
ON BM.[MaslaHal_ID]=MI.ID 
WHERE and BM.ID=2 
AND MI.Masla_status_ID IN(1,2)
```

I've also moved some of the conditions from the `ON` clause to the `WHERE` clause. It should have no effect on the results, but it makes the query more readable.

Comment: Nice! I was to lazy to rewrite without using sub-query :)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is more efficient wa.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select  SUM(CASE WHEN Is_shortlisted=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALSHORLISTED,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Is_Interested=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTALINERESTED 
from (
    SELECT  BM.ID,
            BM.Is_Interested,
            BM.Is_shortlisted,
            BM.Business_Masla_Status_ID
    FROM  Business_Maslahal BM
    INNER join Vw_MaslaInfo MI 
        on BM.[MaslaHal_ID]=MI.ID and BM.ID=2 AND MI.Masla_status_ID IN(1,2) 
) Dtable
```